# After built the Spring-Framework 4.2.6 , castor,jaxb,xmlbeans missed below the program of spring-oxm

Tags: spring, jaxb, xmlbeans, castor, oxm

Everything is find, but the three files :castor,jaxb and xmlbeans.(miss)
They are looks like below:
[image: Three files missed]

Than I try to download the jars. Obviously, it's not work
Post more than 2 links need at least 10 reputation..  so .. the picture I import three jar in my build path , can't upload..
The three jar are castor.jar,jaxb.jar and xmlbeans.jar which I download from jarfire.com.
Than the error below
[image]

I try to figure it out in Chinese Internet, but no such information can help me. 
Any one could help me.

Comment: Don't add information as links to images. Include the information in the post, don't let people who want to help you click links to get a full view of the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I did not mean that. I will avoid do that again